# Unknown column - multiple joins in CDbCriteria

Tags: activerecord, join, yii

I'm trying to get data from multiple tables and I've ended with this error:
SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p.firstname' in 'field list'

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'ohu_id, hash, p.firstname, p.surname, p.city, u.email AS Email';
    $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN `profiles` p ON  p.user_id = user_id';
    $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN users u ON user_id = u.id';
    $criteria->condition = 'offer_id = :oID';
    $criteria->params = array(':oID' => $_GET['id']);

    $model = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Or is there better way to get related data?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are making the same mistake I made hehe.

You are **overwriting** the first join with the second one, instead of **appending the second join**.

```
$criteria->join  = "join ...."; //first join
$criteria->join .= "join ...."; //second join
```

cheers

Answer (score 7):

Actually its way better to user some "with" clause like this:

```
$criteria->with = array(
    'profiles '=>array(
         'select'=>'profiles.user_id',
         'together'=>true
     ),
    'users'=>array(
          'select'=>'users.id',
          'together'=>true
     )
);
```

You can use this also in model searching for CGridView DataProvider.

Answer (score 3):

It's better if you show your database structure. But here it's the solution to join multiple tables using **left join**

Code to join tables:

```
$criteria->select = 'ohu_id, hash, p.firstname, p.surname, p.city, u.email AS Email';
$criteria->alias = 'c';
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN profiles p ON  (p.user_id = c.user_id) LEFT JOIN users u ON (c.user_id = u.id)';
```

Hope it will help you.